# RegisterStartupScript on master page not working. Alternatives?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have tried using RegisterStartupScript and ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to no effect. both are failing to send my list of javascript arrays.

I am doing this on the masterpage's page load and can only assume the fact that I'm doing it on a master page is the problem.

I have the exact same C# code on another page (that is not being loaded at this time and holds different value names, thus will not conflict to create this current issue) and it works flawlessly.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Upon further debugging the problem seems to lie in the fact that the code I send to be written in js from the C# file is being done 'after' it reads the masterpage's javascript somehow.. Though it should have to read the CS file and do it's work first, yeah? Hmph. I'm not sure.

**Edit: FIX'D**

Oh! I found a cheap way around. What I was doing was:

- A) creating arrays in C# to be sent
  to javascript (so creating javascript
  arrays that are already filled)
- B)
  trying to call registerstartupscript
  /RegisterClientScriptBlock

  - C) Getting an error because
    window.onload reads the builder that
    required those variables before
    they're created (god knows why)

**Solution**: instead of using window.onload to run the generator, I put it in the code block I was sending to javascript after I declare the variables. A devilish way that doesn't actually solve the problem, just works around it.

Comment: I will post a portion of my code if anyone wishes, but I highly doubt it is the cause of this problem.

Comment: Is the JavaScript function common to all pages? Otherwise it will be very good if you place the code in Page_Load of content page.

Comment: The code is in the page load. The RegisterStartupScript simply does not write any js code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Odd I've never tried to do that myself in all the years I've been doing this.  What Type are you passing as the first param of RegisterX...X()?

Comment: Through my normal version of this I send this.GetType(). You gave me the idea to try Page.GetType() and this.Master.GetType() but no progress attained.